My R version won't support the pairwiseAdonis package. What can I use instead?
I'm trying to run a pairwise adonis test to follow up with a significant adonis2 test (vegan package) in R 4.4.2 but I keep getting this message:
    install.packages("pairwiseAdonis",dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installation of the package in ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(because ‘lib’ is not specified)
Warning in install.packages :
  the package ‘pairwiseAdonis’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your R version may be available elsewhere,
Check
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Is there another package somewhere that does this test? If not, which test can I use instead of pairwise adonis?

Check the installation instructions. It seems this package is not on public R repositories and you need to install from the github instead:
install.packages('devtools') # Assuming you don't have devtools package already
library(devtools)
install_github("pmartinezarbizu/pairwiseAdonis/pairwiseAdonis")


Thanks, this worked and solved my problem.
